# What happened to my tomatillo?

Tags: tomatillos

Last night we got our first frost. Before nightfall, I went and picked all of the remaining tomatillos in the garden regardless of their ripeness. Some were ripe, some were unripe, and then there was this fellow ...

[image: my tomatillo thinks he's a strawberry]

Is this one so overripe it's gone to seed? Usually I only pick tomatillos when they're ripe -- it's entirely possible I overlooked one and only manage to pick it yesterday when I was indiscriminately pulling everything off the plants.

I have 4 tomatillo plants in a raised bed getting partial (arguably not enough) sunlight and (arguably) too much rain. US mid-Atlantic, agricultural zone 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes the skin bursts (which is what we see here)  - it's not ALWAYS (or perhaps even often) over-ripe; it can happen due to inconsistent rains (or watering) where the fruit swells up so much, so fast, that it cracks open and peels back rather than growing larger.

If I recall correctly, I've also had one do this after picking, so it couldn't have been getting more water, but it may have had a flaw or crack in the skin (and, I suppose, some pre-existing hydrostatic pressure internally) that opened up as it was sitting in the kitchen. I had husked and washed the basketful, so I know it did not go into the basket split open, but it came out that way.

Comment: A few of mine (say 1 in 20) do that as well, every year. Since the fruits otherwise look healthy, I think it's just natural. I grow them in Denmark.